Why do some jump starters start partially depleted batteries for safety reasons?
I was looking at this jump starter In Halfords(if needed see attached pic below) and in the description it says it will “only start partially depleted batteries(batteries not below 3 volts) for safety reasons”.
On the other hand I notice there are similarly priced jump starters that do start fully depleted batteries.
What is the exact safety reason a manufacturer is limiting its starter to partially depleted 3 volts batteries? And with that explanation are the jump starters starting dead batteries considered unsafe or do they have an alternative safety mechanism which the originally Halfords product I was looking at may not have employed?
Thanks


It's about reverse polarity protection. Connecting a 12V source backwards to a car with a totally dead battery will at minimum blow a number of fuses, but may also permanently fry electronic components, resulting in a massive repair bill.
If you connect this jump starter to a 12V device -- say a tire inflator or a handheld spotlight -- the device won't run. There's an internal safety circuit that won't connect the battery to the cable clamps unless it senses voltage on the clamps from a partially charged battery with the proper polarity. The cutoff for this device is 3 volts. I've seen devices that demand as much as 8 volts.
As soon as the jump starter senses voltage of the proper polarity on the clamps, the internal connection to its battery is made, and it's ready to jump start a car.
You can test this with a device such as a tire inflator by connecting the clamps, seeing that the device doesn't run, then momentarily connecting a 9V "transistor" battery to the clamps with the proper polarity. The inflator should start right up.
Jump starters without this feature are not necessarily unsafe, but they are not dummy-proof. They'll work safely as long as you don't hook them up backwards.

In your last paragraph, by don’t hook them up backwards do you mean so long as you connect the red clip to the positive terminal and the black clip to the negative terminal?
And if you do mix them up you will blow car fuses and potentially fry electronics?  Thanks

@JamesWilson Yes, that's exactly what I mean. In other words, they're safe when used as directed but can leave you with expensive damage if you don't pay attention to polarity.
